# Securely Keeping Track of Page Views in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router, pageviews

I would like to do a page views in Meteor.

The issue is that Meteor routes are client side and I can't seem to figure out a way to count each time a page is viewed.

I could do something simple like a method call each time someone visits a page, but clearly this isn't secure.
One option is simply to leave it insecure and make it so someone can only page view once every 15 minutes or so, or keep track of their user_id. The problem with keeping track of user_id's is that it seems like a lot of resources to store every person's id for every page that is visited.

> How do I securely keep track of page views in Meteor?

Answer (score 3):

“Isn’t secure” as in, easily spoofed? Just use Iron Router’s `onBeforeAction` in your route definition:

```
this.route('viewPage', {
  path: '/viewPage/:_id',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    // Put your code for tracking pageviews here
  }
});
```

There’s no way to view the page without the `onBeforeAction` function running first; that’s why this is where apps usually check that a user is logged in (if logged in, render route; otherwise, render login page). See docs: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#before-and-after-hooks

If by “secure” you mean encrypted, follow the Meteor docs to implement user accounts and HTTPS.

Comment: The problem is that if I put the code in the onBeforeAction (some simple Meteor.call()), then someone could find that method and simply call the method repeatedly to mess up my page views. The idea is I want to keep track of trending pages and whatnot, and a simple method call held in Iron Router would allow someone to easily change what's trending.

Comment: Any code you put client-side will still need to be validated server-side; a "logged-in" check, for example, is pretty porous if it's not validated on the server. You can use a Meteor.call, like you said, but on the server side check for trickery before you count the page view. For example have the call send up the page ID and that user's ID, and on the server side check that that user hasn't viewed more than 60 pages in the last hour (or whatever) and hasn't already viewed the current page; and only then increment the counter for that page.